# Help identifying these toys/promo items

Tags: toys, buck-rogers

These items came in with some Buck Rogers items from the 40's/50's.  I have no idea if they are related to Buck Rogers or are just trinkets from the era.

- A pair of rings, one says "Rocket Ship" and the other is a ringed planet.
- A bracelet, has a rocket flying through a ring that says "Space Scout" and back of links say "link pieces" "to form" "bracelet".

[image]

Comment: Hi. What are the rings made out of?

Comment: Are there any marks on the reverse or sides?

Comment: The bright yellow plastic of the bracelet makes me think it's pretty new - it would be discolored if old.  This all looks like stuff out of cereal boxes or Cracker Jack boxes. If you're outside the US, perhaps even a Kinder Egg.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the reverse, especially any makers marks or text?

Comment: Rings are plastic, no markings anywhere else.

Comment: The bracelet does look newer, but could have been made of better quality or stored correctly?  The only markings on them are the words I quoted, they are on the backs of the links